# Beta meta site descriptions are wrong on SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Code Review Meta's description:

> Q&A for peer programmer code reviews

This is the same as the description for Code Review itself. In keeping with the description for the non-beta metas, this should probably instead be:

> Q&A about the Site for peer programmer code reviews

This same bug shows up I think for all the newly-introduced beta meta sites on SEDE.

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved.

I have updated the script that imports new sites to be consistent when naming Meta sites. I also went ahead and updated the existing Taglines for all sites.